# Lambda Handler to invoke Python script directly

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm not a Python developer but I got stuck with taking over the maintenance of a Python 3.9 project that currently runs as a cronjob on an EC2 instance. I need to get it running from AWS Lambda. Currently the crontab on the EC2 instance invokes a `cronjob/run.py` script that looks a little like this:

```
import os
import sys

from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
sync_events = get_sync_events()
# lots more stuff down here
```

The important thing here is that there is *no* `__main__` method invoked. The crontab just treats this Python source file like a script and executes it from top to bottom.

My *understanding* is that the Lambda Handler *needs* a main method to be invoked. So I need a way to run the existing `cronjob/run.py` (that again, has no main entry point) from inside the Lambda Handler, somehow:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        # run everything thats in cronjob/run.py right here
        raise e
    except Exception as e:
        raise e

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lambda_handler(None, None)
```

So my question: do I *need* my Lambda Handler to have a `__main__` method like the above, or is it possible to configure my Lambda to just call `cronjob/run.py` directly? If not, what are the best options here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, you expressly should not have an `__main__` test that runs the Lambda function handler. The AWS Lambda service will invoke the configured Lambda function handler at the relevant time, passing event and context. Use them as you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> do I need my Lambda Handler to have a **main** method

No, you don't.

If you just want to run `run.py` with lambda, you can keep things simple and just use:

```
import os
import sys
from dotenv import load_dotenv

def main(event, context):         
    load_dotenv()
    sync_events = get_sync_events()
    # lots more stuff down here
```

and configure the lambda function to have `run.main` as the handler.

The name of the handler function, in this case `main`, can be anything, but it must have `event` and `context` as arguments.

You can find more information on lambda handler here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-handler.html

Comment: Thanks @Paolo (+1) - just to confirm: **(1)** if I add the `def main(event, context): return` to the bottom of the `cronjob/run.py` sourcefile, that will make that file "runnable" from Lambda's perspective?

Comment: **(2)** I have the entire Python project in an S3 bucket. In reality the `cronjob/run.py` source file references source code in lots of other Python files as well (and not just those inside the `cronjob/` dir). Are Lambdas _supposed_ to just be single Python/JS files? Or is there a way to fetch the entire project from S3, "deploy" it to the Lambda, and configure `cronjob/run.py` `main` method as the starting point?

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup (1), yes. (2), you can have multiple Python files in a lambda function. There's no automated way to do that; pull the files from S3 and you could use something like sam to package and deploy your lambda https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/what-is-sam.html

Comment: (you don't have to use sam, but it will make your life easier)

Comment: Thank you again @Paolo (+1 again) -- what's you're recommendation for "pulling" the files from S3? Use the `aws lambda update-function-code` CLI tool perhaps?

Comment: You can use something like aws s3 cp to copy the files to your local machine.